# Form validation feedback colors

Tags: html, css, colors, formatting

I have a login page that I need to notify the user when they put in the wrong user name and password. I can handle all the validation stuff, but my question is what colors should I use that will grab the user's attention that something is wrong and says "Look at me!"? I posted an example of the colors I currently have. The background is the color I have to use, but I need to know what color to change the textbox background and the error message to. I need the colors to look professional and go with the background color.

http://jsfiddle.net/GE3Cg/1/

Comment: Graphic design question? Maybe belongs on Doctype. Doesn't really belong on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using jQuery, check out the jQuery UI [Theme Gallery](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#themeGallery) for really nice preset colors. You can also roll your own if you want.

Answer (score 1):

check out messages.css in this github repo (it's mine yes) [it's got colour schemes and icons already done for ya.](https://github.com/jonezy/css-base/blob/master/messages.css)

Comment: That's pretty cool, but I won't be able to use it on this project. Very particular users :( .